OpenSearch machine learning Payload not working
I have the following code:
payload = {
    "parameters": {
        "centroids": 3,
        "iterations": 10,
        "distance_type": "COSINE"
    },
    "input_query": {
        "_source": ["description_embedding_ada_2", "title_embedding_ada_2",],
        "size": 200
    },
    "input_index": ["test-main-index",]
}

# Convert the payload to JSON
payload_json = json.dumps(payload)

# Set the timeout value (in seconds)
timeout = 60  # Increase the timeout to 60 seconds

# Send the request to OpenSearch
response = os_client.transport.perform_request(
    method='POST',
    url='/_plugins/_ml/_train/kmeans',
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body=payload_json,
    timeout=timeout
)

# Print the response
print(response)

When executing the code I am getting the following error:
RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'unsupported type:java.util.ArrayList')
Okay, i assumed that input_index might not need an Array.
Once I changed "input_index": ["test-main-index",] to "input_index": "test-main-index" I got the following error:
RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Failed to parse object: expecting token of type [START_ARRAY] but found [VALUE_STRING]')
So it seems like it wants an Array again?
What am I doing wrong? I have tried lots of options, but I cannot understand what is wrong. The problem is not at the os_client side, because I can send other Payloads without any problem...
